# How to Access Class from a Different Class?

Tags: c#

I have a problem here with my BlackJack program. This is the code in BlackJack.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class blackjack
    {

    static string[] playercards = new string[11];
    static string hitstay = "";
    static int total = 0, count = 1, dealertotal = 0;
    static Random cardshuffler = new Random();
    static Form1 f1 = new Form1();




    public static void start()
    {


        dealertotal = cardshuffler.Next(15, 22);
        playercards[0] = deal();
        playercards[1] = deal();
        f1.TextValue = "test";

        bj();

    }


    private static void hit()
    {

        count += 1;
        playercards[count] = deal();
        f1.playertb.Text += "you were dealed a(n) " + playercards[count] + ".your new total is " + total + ".";
        if (total.Equals(21))
        {
            f1.playertb.Text += "you got blackjack! the dealer's total was " + dealertotal + ".would you like to play again?";
            playagain();
        }
        else if (total > 21)
        {
            f1.playertb.Text += "you busted, therefore you lost. sorry. the dealer's total was " + dealertotal + ".would you like to play again? y/n";
            playagain();
        }
        else if (total < 21)
        {
            do
            {
                f1.playertb.Text += "would you like to hit or stay?";

            } while (!hitstay.Equals(f1.Hit) && !hitstay.Equals(f1.Stay));
            bj();
        }
    }

    private static string deal()
    {
        string Card = "";
        int cards = cardshuffler.Next(1, 14);
        switch (cards)
        {
            case 1: Card = "Two"; total += 2;
                break;
            case 2: Card = "Three"; total += 3;
                break;
            case 3: Card = "Four"; total += 4;
                break;
            case 4: Card = "Five"; total += 5;
                break;
            case 5: Card = "Six"; total += 6;
                break;
            case 6: Card = "Seven"; total += 7;
                break;
            case 7: Card = "Eight"; total += 8;
                break;
            case 8: Card = "Nine"; total += 9;
                break;
            case 9: Card = "Ten"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 10: Card = "Jack"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 11: Card = "Queen"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 12: Card = "King"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 13: Card = "Ace"; total += 11;
                break;

        }
        return Card;
    }

    static void bj()
    {
        if (hitstay.Equals (f1.Hit))
        {
            hit();
        }
        else if (hitstay.Equals(f1.Stay))
        {
            if (total > dealertotal && total <= 21)
            {
 f1.PlayerText += "you won! the dealer busted with " + dealertotal + " as their total" + "your total was " + total;
                playagain();
            }
            else if (total < dealertotal)
            {
 f1.PlayerText += "sorry, you lost! the dealer's total was " + dealertotal;
                playagain();
            }

        }
    }

    private static void playagain()
    {



    }


}
}
```

Now here is my Form1.cs code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{



public partial class Form1 : Form
{



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    public void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show
            ("Are You Sure You Want To Close?",
            "",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            e.Cancel = true;

    }



        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         BetForm betForm = new BetForm();


        betForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        if (betForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You bet  $" + betForm.Bet);
        }
    }

    public string TextValue
    {

        set
        {
            playertb.Text = value;
        }

    }





 public string PlayerText
  {
   get { return playertb.Text; }
   set { playertb.Text = value; }
  }

    private void Stay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blackjack.start();
    }   


}
}
```

The problem is that when i press the "Play" button on the form it is supposed to perform start() in the BlackJack class. When it performs it something is supposed to be written in "playertb" which is a textbox. Nothing gets written in the textbox and I can't do anything about it. Please help.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so I'd suggest tagging it as such.

Answer (score 0):

In the blackjack class, you create a second instance of Form1 called f1, but you never show it.  You call blackjack.Start() from your first instance of Form1.

To fix the immediate problem, you might try the following:

```
static Form1 f1 = null;   // declare it, but don't initialise it (we'll get 
                          // it when start() is called )

public static void start(Form1 form)
    {

        // set the static reference to the calling form,

        f1 = form

        dealertotal = cardshuffler.Next(15, 22);
        playercards[0] = deal();
        playercards[1] = deal();
        f1.TextValue = "test";

        bj();

    }
```

then, in your Form1 class,

```
blackjack.start(this);
```

Although, if I was designing this myself, I would make `blackjack` a non-static class with a constructor.  At the moment, you're only able to have 1 game of blackjack running at a time.  I would then signal changes in the game via events.  This prevents the situation where the blackjack class has to know about Form1.  In principle, blackjack should know very little or nothing about the UI layer.  This makes your code far more portable and reusable.

Comment: i typed 'static blackjack blaj = new blackjack' in form1 and used it istead of blackjack.start and then i get an error saying this:
Member 'WindowsFormsApplication1.blackjack.start()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @Charlie: It is NOT true that a class w/o a constructor cannot be instantiated. If you don't know what you're talking about, it's best not to say anything. That way, you're not misinforming people.

Comment: @Charlie: Also, static classes have constructors as well; their constructors, however, just like their methods, are static as well.

Comment: @Esteban well I'd say you should be more careful then :) In c# if you do not explicitly declare any constructors that class will still have the default constructor someClass(). So in otherwords any concrete class will have a constructor and can _therefor_ be instantiated. You can however have types without constructors. Interfaces are types but they do not have any constructors and can therefor not be instantiated. On the other hand you can have types with constructors that cannot be instantiated. List<> i a type but cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Esteban: Yes you're absolutely correct.  I misunderstood the OP's comment.  He was doing `WindowsFormsApplication1.blackjack.start()` when she should be doing `blaj.start()` although I suspect he's still going to have issues if he still has 2 instances of Form1.